# divide/cutting SVG in boxes, RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, html5-canvas, raphael

I am using RaphaelJS to draw 4 boxes inside a canvas.

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 512, 256);

var rectangle = paper.rect(50, 50, 50, 50),
    rectangle2 = paper.rect(400, 50, 50, 50);
    rectangle3 = paper.rect(50, 200, 50, 50);
    rectangle4 = paper.rect(400, 200, 50, 50);

rectangle2.attr("fill", "red");
rectangle3.attr("fill", "green");
rectangle4.attr("fill", "blue");
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SFRWj/1/

--

My problem: I want to loop and cut/divide my svg canvas in 4: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right
Purpose: I want to have 4 separate elements I can then try to convert to png or base64 or just do something with them.

any ideas?

---

UPDATE 1:

with two `for` loops and

`paper.setViewBox(i*viewStep,j*viewStep,128,128,false);`

I got something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SFRWj/3/

---

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/) but you can probably achieve the same with Raphael:

```
var src = 'http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/89ac2e90d9b111e297bf22000a1f9263_7.jpg'

/* create canvases */
var draw1 = SVG('canvas1').viewbox(0,0,75,75)
var draw2 = SVG('canvas2').viewbox(75,0,75,75)
var draw3 = SVG('canvas3').viewbox(0,75,75,75)
var draw4 = SVG('canvas4').viewbox(75,75,75,75)

/* draw image */
var image = draw1.image(src).size(150,150)

/* clone image to other canvases */
draw2.add(image.clone())
draw3.add(image.clone())
draw4.add(image.clone())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wout/rgzG6/

This example basically created four svg canvases, clones the content from the first to the other canvases and sets a viewbox for everyone of them. If you have multiple elements you could consider putting everything in a group before cloning them.

Comment: thanks for taking the time on this @wout, I found something similar with canvg.js and exporting to .png base64. I will give both a try and post the results. Thanks!